# Firestore query sometimes doesn't contain updated data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using firestore's node sdk. In my code I call function1, which updates a table in firestore. When that function ends I call function2, which runs a query to get a reference of the table. About 80% of the time it works, but sometimes the data I need, which was added to the document in function1 doesn't come back in the snapshot so an error is thrown.

I added an await keyword before the update, but that doesn't seem to make the code wait for the firestore update to complete.

I suppose I could also return the data I was going to update in function1 and pass it into function2, but that feels kind of hacky, though I suppose I'd save a little money because I wouldn't have to get 1 document anymore. I could also make it one big function, but that would make it an 100 line function.

Here's an abbreviated version of my code:

```
const function1 = async (tableId) => {
      const firestore = admin.firestore();
      const tableSnapshot = await firestore.collection('tables').doc(tableId).get();
      await tableSnapshot.ref.update({ smallBlind: {seat: 1, amount: 5000} }) // the seat number and amount number wont always be 1 and 5000. Otherwise I wouldn't need to look it up in function2
}

const function2 = async (tableId) => {
      const firestore = admin.firestore();
      const tableSnapshot = await firestore.collection('tables').doc(tableId).get();
      const tableData = tableSnapshot.data();
      const smallBlind = tableSnapshot.data().smallBlind; // the smallBlind data is not there. so smallBlind is undefined
}

const startStuff = async () => {
   await function1(42); // example tableId is passed in
   await function2(42);
}
startStuff()
```

Comment: Does this also occur if you take a `promise.then()` approach in your code?

Comment: @ralemos I haven't tried that, but since async/await is syntactic sugar for promises I don't see why that would matter.

Comment: You are correct, I suggested that because this appear to be a synchronicity issue and it would be easier to troubleshoot using that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code has no async issues. I had a different async issue in another portion of my code, which caused my problem.